# Twitter Bootstrap table transparent css issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a table thats being generated from a SQL database. It has the following:

```
<table id="Email" width="725px" height="780" border="0" cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#551155">
```

As you can see it uses the bgColor attribute, which I know is getting phased out etc. But right now I have to dump it as is and not find/replace the output.

Now I am using twitter bootstrap that pretty much overrides that background color, in the bootstrap CSS:

```
table {
max-width: 100%;
background-color: transparent;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}
```

As you can see it sets the table's background to transparent. Is there a clever way to override this? Without modifying the HTML output or the bootstrap file?

I tried creating another class in my override css style file, but I don't see many options to set for background-color other than inherit.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just do not add `bgcolor` attribute, it's now deprecated. What you should do is to:

1. Create another CSS file, link it to the HTML page and make sure it's at the bottom most of any other CSS link tags.

   1. Add a class to your table, for example `<table class="set-bg"></table>`
   2. Add style to your newly created CSS file

      `.set-bg {
         background-color: #551155;
         ...
      }`

The key point is to include your own CSS file after the CSS Bootstrap file.